# JAXB Unmarshal Exception

Tags: namespaces, jaxb

I generated some classes off of an xsd that I made from a web service response that I am calling.
I'm getting an Exception when I run a JUnit test class that reads in an InputStream from the web service call.
I'm stuck as to what the exception means, so I'm looking for some ideas on things to check:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected element {http://bar.foo.com/bbs}:rule
```

I have a class in my generated classes at:

```
com.foo.bar.bbs.Rule
```

Does the Exception mean I do not have the Rule class in the proper package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are unmarshalling the correct type of object.

Answer (score 3):

The following are some things to check:

**@XmlRootElement**

Check that the Rule class is annotated with @XmlRootElement:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Rule {
}
```

**@XmlElementDecl**

Or that there is a corresponding @XmlElementDecl in the ObjectFactory class:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://bar.foo.com/bbs", name = "root")
public JAXBElement<Root> createCustomer(Root value) {
    return new JAXBElement<BigInteger>(_ROOT_QNAME, Root.class, null, value);
}
```

**@XmlSchema**

You will also need to ensure that the namespace information is specified correctly.  A package-info class was probably generated something like the following for you.  Ensure the correct namespace is specified.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://bar.foo.com/bbs", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.foo.bar.bbs;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Alternatively you could include the namespace in the @XmlRootElement annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://bar.foo.com/bbs")
public class Rule {
}
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html